# Is it possible to extract ActionScript from swf files?

Tags: linux, command-line, flash, swf, actionscript-3

I'm desperately searching for a command line tool that allows you to extract ActionScript from an SWF file on linux. I need only the ActionScript part, not the assets.

Answer (score 0):

Use one of the following tools to extract `.as` files from a `.swf` file:

- [Flash Decompiler](https://code.google.com/p/flash-decompiler/)
- [Flare](http://www.nowrap.de/flare.html)